# Looking for dynamic network data sets

Tags: graphs, data-sets, social-networks, big-data

There are a number of collections of network (or graph) data sets freely available on the web, e.g.

- http://snap.stanford.edu/data/index.html
- http://www.cc.gatech.edu/dimacs10/downloads.shtml

I am looking for dynamic network data sets, i.e. networks whose structure varies over time. They seem to be quite rare: The SNAP collection contains only a few "temporal" graphs.

Do you known any other possible sources?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's looking for data sets, not asking a question. It would be more suited for a wiki site.

Comment: I have posted a somewhat related question (with bounty!) here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382260/temporal-generalization-of-graphs-density-vs-n-and-m